# Point pip to anaconda pip

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I was trying to install a Python package that was developed by myself using the command `pip install -e.`. However, when I ran my code, I found that the code was run by Python 2.7 instead of Python 3.7, which is the version that I use on my desktop. When I ran the command `which pip`, I got `/home/username/.local/bin/pip` instead of `/home/username/anaconda3/bin/pip`. Therefore, I was wondering if there is a way that can make `pip` points to `/home/username/anaconda3/bin/pip` instead of `/home/username/.local/bin/pip`. (However, even if I use `pip3 install -e.`, my code was still run by Python 2.7, so I really wasn't sure about the reason why the code was run in version 2.7...)

Another thing is that I found that the `numpy` module could not be found after I upgraded `pip`. That's pretty weird to me since after running the commands `python2` or `python3`, I could import `numpy` in both cases, which means that the `numpy` module has been already installed. Based on this, I was not sure which Python was being run so that the `numpy` module could not be found. For your information (if that helps), here is the output of the command `whereis pip`:

```
pip: /usr/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip3.6 /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 /usr/local/bin/pip /home/username/.local/bin/pip3.6 /home/username/.local/bin/pip /home/username/anaconda3/bin/pip /home/username/anaconda3/bin/pip3.7 /usr/share/man/man1/pip.1.gz
```

This has been frustrating to me. I appreciate any experience shared.

Comment: Are you using Conda's environments https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html? This issue seems like a good candidate for a Conda environment, since your goal is to separate your local workstation python dependencies (pip in this case) from your Conda workspace. It's been a while, but I'm pretty sure that if you create a Conda environment and activate it, you'll be explicitly using that environment's pip instance, and installing into that environment's dependencies.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I was using the base environment. I think it is doable to separate dependencies in a virtual (conda) environment, but I was wondering if that is possible in the base environment.